# How to get smoother background size animations?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have the following code:-

[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a3zv3L5w/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="pb-stars"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}

#pb-stars {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/pb-stars.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1075px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('#pb-stars').animate({
    'background-size': '110%'
}, 28000);
```

The problem I have is that the animation is a bit 'jerky', is there any way to get this animation running any smoother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the easing to 'linear' like so:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a3zv3L5w/1/)

```
jQuery('#pb-stars').animate({
    'background-size': '110%'
}, 28000, 'linear');
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a bit, would it make it any smoother using `transform: translate3d(0, -110%, 0);`?

Answer (score 0):

To have a smoother animation you have to reduce the time of execution, because jquery do linear animation and fill all the time needed with a thing to do.
I putted it around **5000** and it works fine. ;)

Comment: I would set it to 5000 but the animation runs too quickly